# Why does my browser send two requests in a post ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have put a link in my web page with the following a tag:

```
<a href="" onclick="FiltrarxUnidadPolitica(1)">
   <label class="filter-item-title">
      Distrito Capital
   </label>
   <label class="filter-item-quantity">
      (3)
   </label>
</a>
```

And the js function that is called when the link is clicked is as follow:

```
function FiltrarxUnidadPolitica(iIdUnidadPolitica, bLimpiarPropiedad) {
   $.ajax({
      data: { iIdUnidadPolitica, bLimpiarPropiedad },
      url: "/Home/ListadoInmuebles",
      type: 'POST',
   });
}
```

The issue that I have is when the link is clicked and the js function is executed the browser makes two requests to the server as you can see in the picture inserted (pending calls), the first one the POST call included in the js function and the second one that is a GET call that I don't know how is initiated.

[image: Browser network calls]

Does anyone know where is comming from the GET call?

Could anyone give me a clue about where I have to look for?

Comment: Cancel the default action of the `a` element by adding `return false` in the body of your function `FiltrarxUnidadPolitica`.

Comment: ^^---will also need a `return` statement at the call site: `<a href="" onclick="return FiltrarxUnidadPolitica(1)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is being followed by the browser, because you haven't told it not to follow it. (`href=""` is the same as "the current page.")

Several ways you can prevent that:

- Don't use a link for something that isn't a link, use an `input type="button"` or `button` and style it to look how you want it to look (this will also help with assistive software).

   *(If you use `button`, make sure it's either not in a `form` or it has `type="button"`; the default type of buttons is, bizarrely, `"submit"`.)*
- Hook up your function with jQuery instead of an `onclick` attribute and call `preventDefault` on the event object.
- Set `href` to `javascript:;`

  ```
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="FiltrarxUnidadPolitica(1);">
  ```

  *(Or to `href="javascript:void(0)"`.)*
- Set `href` to `#anchor-that-does-not-exist`

  *(Don't use `href="#"` unless you want the page to scroll to the top when the link is followed.)*
- Add a `return false` to the `onclick`:

  ```
  <a href="" onclick="FiltrarxUnidadPolitica(1); return false;">
  ```

  Returning `false` from a DOM0 attribute-style handler prevents the default action; more on my blog: [*The true story on `return false`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).

Probably others as well...

Answer (score -1):

> Preflighted requests
>
> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP OPTIONS request header to the resource on the other
>   domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to
>   send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data. In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET or POST. Also, if POST is used to send
>   request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted. It sets
>   custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as
>   X-PINGOTHER)

Source: MDN

Comment: This only applies to cross-domain requests